# angular Js call function outside of given function

Tags: angularjs, function-calls

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
       getmydata = function() {
            return $http.get("getConnectionData.php").then(function (response) {
                         $scope.links1 = response.data.records;
                   });

               }

              getmydata().then(function(data) {
              // stuff is now in our scope, I can alert it
              console.log("hiiiii" , $scope.links1);
              });


 });
```

Here I want to call this section outside of dragend function-  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

```
getmydata().then(function(data) {
    // stuff is now in our scope, I can alert it
     console.log("hiiiii" , $scope.links1);
});
```

How can I do this .

Answer (score 1):

you can write something like this

```
   getmydata2=function(data){
      console.log("hiiiii" , data);
   }

   getmydata = function() {
        return $http.get("getConnectionData.php").then(function (response) {
                     $scope.links1 = response.data.records;
                     getmydata2($scope.links1);
               });

   }

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', getmydata);
```

you can now call it wherever you want

Comment: I want the data after drag function..Because I need updated data and when I am making drag I am getting updated data

Comment: check it out once again plz

Comment: TypeError: f.j.apply is not a function

Comment: use google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', getmydata);

Answer (score 1):

You need to return data from the `$http.get` call

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
   getmydata = function() {
       return $http.get("getConnectionData.php").then(function (response) {
                 return response;
           });
       }

      getmydata().then(function(data) {
      // stuff is now in our scope, I can alert it
      $scope.links1 = data;
      console.log("hiiiii" , $scope.links1);
      });
 });
```

Comment: I am returning the data from $http.get                                                                            $scope.links1 = data;